# ASP.NET or PHP - How to browse Windows File System as Ldap Authenticated User

Tags: php, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, filesystems

In PHP - If you authenticate a user with LDAP - is it possible to use those credentials to browse the Windows File System - i.e. read files and directories as though you are that user, and not the Web Server's user.

If this is possible, what's the best way to store those credentials, as clearly storing them in plain text is not an option.

Alternatively - If working with the Windows File System is not suggested using PHP - I'm looking at writing the application in ASP.NET Core MVC - I know you can use Windows Login - but that doesn't seem to give you the option of form-based login - as it's mainly meant for internal intranet applications.

Is there a way to use LDAP authentication in ASP.NET Core MVC and store those credentials to them make a connection to a share as that user.

Whichever way - I do not want to be managing file systems permissions in PHP - I want to make a connection to file system and let it do the access/denying based on the credentials provided.

I hope this makes sense! Any other suggestions are welcome!

Edit: I am most comfortable with PHP - so if there's a way to do it in PHP that would be best. However I'm open to either option.

Comment: Yes you can do it in PHP; you can use [ldap_list](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ldap-list.php) to list a directory . From my short bit of research I don't think it's possible to use anything but plain text when making a connection to LDAP using [ldap_bind](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ldap-bind.php)

Comment: ldap_list lists objects in the LDAP tree - I'm looking to browse a windows file server share with the LDAP authenticated user's permissions. Thank you for your comment though. Unless I'm missing something -.-.

Comment: I would suggest giving a try. I would have thought it would work however.

Comment: Can you please provide an example of what you mean - as ldap_list as far as I know is for browsing the LDAP structure.